# Bootstrap-table, data filters are css positioned as absolute

Tags: css, filter, bootstrap-4, position, bootstrap-table

I need to do some work on acode that was written with bootstrap-table.
columns were defined with data-sotrable attribute.

```
<th data-field="Severity" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Severity</th>
```

resulting in the filters being positioned as absolutes, inside the `<th>` columns :

```
    <th><div class="th-inner sortable both">Sort</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th>
```

What is the best way to move the filters(class="fhr-cell") from the th?
They need to be positioned as relative, abouve the grid.